# how to make onttomany relationship in spring hibernate

Tags: spring

I am trying to relate two tables with spring / hibernate in MYSQL    like this

```
    @Table (name = candidatresumeinfo)
    public class CandidateResumeInfo implements Serializable
      {
     List<SelectedResumes> selectedResumes;
       .............
         ..............

     @JoinColumn(name = "selectedresumeid")
 @OneToMany
public List<SelectedResumes> getSelectedResumes() {
    return selectedResumes;
}
public void setSelectedResumes(List<SelectedResumes> selectedResumes) {
    this.selectedResumes = selectedResumes;
}
```

Now ,i got the data in my list correctly( i checked in debug)but the call from server is getting failed which is saying cause:Nullpointer exception  .

thanks

Comment: Please provide the stacktrace and other informations about your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `OneToMany` annotation **only on Collections**, so you should change the field to **Set or List**, because hibernate will return multiple result if you use OneToMany. I think you'd like to use ManyToOne annotation here.

- `ManyToOne` means here that you have **multiple CandidateResumeInfo for one SelectedResumes**.
- `OneToMany` means here that you have **multiple SelectedResumes for one CandidateResumeInfo**.

This annotation naming can be a bit strange for first time. Hope I helped.

**Answer for your comment:**

The best way is you declare the relationship both side.
Here is the example:

**CandidateResumeInfo.java:**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="candidateResumeInfo")
List<SelectedResumes> selectedResumes;
```

**SelectedResumes.java:**

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="candidate_resume_info_id")
CandidateResumeInfo candidateResumeInfo;
```

Comment: thanks abalogh , i changed it to set as you said , now i am getting this error   : invocation of initmethod failed, nested exception is org.hibernate.annotationexception ,mapped by reference an unknown target entity property     >>  any idea whats the reason

Comment: I wrote you down the example in the answer.

Comment: thanks abalogh ,  that exception was removed , thanks lepike , i am trying your way , hope it works  thanks

Comment: i tried the list thing , the error removed but server call is getting failed ,i changed my question above kindly review